# Laravel edit Product, set correct selected (with many-to-many)

Tags: php, laravel, collections

I have a system where a User has Shops and Shops have Products.

Now a Shop can have many Products, and a Product can belong to many Shops. When a User adds a new Product he/she can choose for which Shop he/she wants to add it

Shops

```
+----+---------+----------------+
| id | user_id |      name      |
+----+---------+----------------+
|  1 |       1 | My First Shop  |
|  2 |       1 | My Second Shop |
+----+---------+----------------+
```

Shop_Products

```
+---------+------------+-----------+
| shop_id | product_id |   image   |
+---------+------------+-----------+
|       1 |          1 | beer.jpg  |
|       1 |          2 | wine.jpg  |
|       1 |          3 | vodka.jpg |
+---------+------------+-----------+
```

> My issue is when a User edits a Product I want to pre-populate the Shop select dropdown with the current Shop this product is assigned to..

But offcourse the following query **returns a Collection** hence the many-to-many

```
$product = Product::findOrFail($id)->shops
```

in my view, to set the correct select option selected I'm trying the following

```
@foreach(\Auth::user()->shops as $shop)
    <option value="{{ $shop->id }}" @if($shop->id == $product->shop->id) selected @endif>{{ $shop->description }}</option>
@endforeach
```

**$product->shop->id isn't working, because $product->shop is a collection**

Looking forward to your ideas! Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think in your situation you could use the `contains` method on a collection (https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#method-contains)

Example:

```
@foreach(\Auth::user()->shops as $shop)
    <option value="{{ $shop->id }}" {{ $product->shops->contains('id', $shop->id) ? "selected" : "" }} >{{ $shop->description }}</option>
@endforeach
```

The code `$product->shops->contains('id', $shop->id)` checks if the shops collection contains a key value combination of `'id'` and `$shop->id`

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
@foreach(\Auth::user()->shops as $shop)
    <option value="{{ $shop->id }}" {{ in_array($shop->id, $product->shops->pluck('id')) ? 'selected' : ''  }}>{{ $shop->description }}</option>
@endforeach
```

using the pluck method on your collection permits to return all the ids of your shops :)

Answer (score 0):

I think this would be a perfect candidate for the `pluck()` method, I believe you can do this:

```
$shops = Product::findOrFail($id)->shops()->pluck('description', 'id');
```

And in your view you can do this:

```
@foreach ($shops as $key => $value) {
  <option value="{{ $key }}">{{ $value }}</option>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score -1):

use `shop_id` instead of `$product->shop->id`

```
@foreach(\Auth::user()->shops as $shop)
    <option value="{{ $shop->id }}" @if($shop->id == $product->shop_id) selected @endif>{{ $shop->description }}</option>
@endforeach
```

Comment: The shop_id is not available since the Product is just the Product, not the many-to-many relation.